# MegaCLI Doesn't allow configured and unconfigured drives with no foreign configs found

Tags: megaraid, megacli

I'm fairly new to MegaCLI and I've been having this one issue, after running

> megacli -CfgLdAdd -r1 [252:0,252:1,252:2,252:3,252:6,252:7] -a0

I get the error

> Mix of configured and unconfigured drives are not possible.
> Exit Code: 0x0b

which upon a quick search shows to run the command

> megacli -CfgForeign -Clear -a0

which returned this

> There is no foreign configuration on controller 0.
> Exit Code: 0x00

My issue is that I can't configure the drives because megacli returns an error but all the info I could find says to do another command for foreign configs which aren't there.

Slight update/edit:
Running command

> megacli -CfgLdAdd -r0 [252:1] -a0

In an effort to just go drive by drive it returns

> The specified physical disk does not have the appropriate attributes to complete
> the requested command.
> Exit Code: 0x26

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A complete normal reboot may help (in order to restart an adapter/controller). Just in case, `megacli -pdlist -a0 | grep -i 'foreign'` should list foreign. Also, read online that the issue source may be a damaged drive or controller. For example, https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/asus-pike-2208-problem.78952/page-2